# Python can't find module in the same folder even when jupyter notebooks can

Tags: python, path, jupyter

In a jupyter notebook I am trying to import a module that is in the same folder as it. This module is of course a .py file, I'll call it util.py, and util.py itself is trying to import another module, call it common.py, which is also in the same folder. When I try to run the jupyter notebook I get an error tracing to util.py, saying "No module named 'common'". What's really strange is If I try importing common.py directly in a jupyter notebook in the same folder, it works just fine. So notebook files can find this module, but not .py files.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _import a module that is in the same folder as it_ Imports will look in the _current directory_, which is not necessarily the same directory as the script.

Comment: @JohnGordon How do I tell python what I want the directory to be?

Comment: Try `from . import common`